# Add brackets around a string

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of string like so.

```
'A' 'B' 'C'
```

I would like to add a bracket around each so it becomes:

```
'(A)' '(B)' '(C)'
```

I've tried the below where first_term_1 is A but that makes the its a 1x3 cell which is of no use to me.

```
new=['(' first_term_1 ')']
```

The whole point of this is for me to generate a simplified equation using a set of obtuse mathematical rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> t = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
>> strcat('(', t, ')')
ans = 
    '(A)'    '(B)'    '(C)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close!  Just need to use curly braces to break out of the cells:

```
my_strings = {'A','B','C'};
new_string = ['(' my_strings{1} ')'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t = { 'A' 'B' 'C' }
fcn = @(a) sprintf ( '(%s)', a )
newCell = cellfun ( fcn, t, 'UniformOutput', false )
```

Comment: Thanks for that, would this work as well to add an inverse sign? fcn = @(a) sprintf ('1/(%s)'), a );
output = cellfun ( fcn, t, 'UniformOutput', false );

Comment: @Trippy `strcat('1/(', t, ')')`